# Check n previous/consecutive numbers of a value (v) of a variable in R

Tags: r

If i have the following variable:

```
numbers<-c(1,2,3,-5,4,5,6,-5,1,2,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,1,1,5
,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,78,78,78,78,78,78,78,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,0,0,0,0,0,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,-5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-5,-5,0,0)
```

I first want to find all -5 values:

```
index<-which(numbers == -5)
[1]   4   8  95 101 135 150 151
value<-numbers[which(numbers == -5)]
[1] -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5
```

What i now want to do is check the **5 values before and after** the positions where **-5 occurs** and see if all values are equal **0** and if that is so keep the starting index of it (`index`) if not delete it from `index`:

So in the following case the desired result would be:

```
r
95 101 135
```

Well i have managed to solve the problem with two independent for loops and one if condition and one temporary list of 2 (one element saving the index numbers one the values) and a variable for storing the result.

But well Iam sure there is a better/shorter/faster result for that?
Anyone any suggestions? In the best of cases I would prefer a base R answer if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
which(
  stats::filter(numbers == 0L,#logical vector 
                c(rep(1, 5), 0, rep(1, 5)) #sum 5 preceding and following logical values
  ) == 10L & #10 TRUE values?
    numbers == -5L
)
#[1]  95 101 135
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
index[sapply(index, function(x) all(!numbers[setdiff(pmax(1,
       x-5):pmin(x+5, length(numbers)), x)]))]
#[1]  95 101 135
```